# Fixed issue where or that?

Tags: that, where

### What is correct?

> "I have fixed an issue where contracts are not saved into the
>   database."

or

> "I have fixed an issue that contracts are not saved into the
>   database."

### The context

The sentence was a comment to a code fix that I was pushing into our code repository.

---

Another question would be whether to use "contracts are" or "contracts were".

Comment: WE need a great deal more context to understand this.

Comment: Definitely, *where* and *were*... in fact, the full sentence should read "Fixed issue where contract *records* were not *being* saved in the database". [This comment is only half the help it should be though. Please, as someone who has to read such comments, say a little bit about what you did so someone reading that will understand more about what the source of the problem was.]

Comment: @TimWard I realised the "were not being" later on. [About the comment: I have omitted a link to the task the commit was assigned to in order not to confuse the reader of this question. Therefore, I believe the comment is sufficient.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I have fixed an issue where contracts were not saved into the database." is correct on the given context.

["Where" presents the situation or condition you are about to describe](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Awhere&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

["That" is similar, because it points to a specific *thing*. However it does not by itself describe a *situation*.](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Awhere&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=off&q=define:that) You would use "That" to draw attention to an object that *is part of* a situation or condition.

So you could say: "I have fixed an issue that caused contracts to not save into the database." or "I have fixed an issue that did not save contracts into the database."

Here is another example:

"Here is the house where I live."

"Here is the house that I live in."

In this example you see that "where I live" and "I live in" are the condition or situation being described, and "that" is a tool for introducing the situation.

In many cases using "where" (or "which") leads to a faster and simpler sentence by being a single word introduction of the situation.

( on the sub-question: "Were" is preferable to "are", since the problem has already been fixed and is no longer occurring; so it belongs to the past. )

( Technical Footnote:
In each of the examples here "That" is actually pointing back to an object in the sentence, not an object in the situation.

"an issue that" - "that" calls attention to "an issue" before you describe the situation which it causes.

"the house that" - "that" calls attention to "the house" before describing the condition of your relationship to it.

"Which" is pointing forward to the situation in every case. )

Comment: "I have fixed an issue that caused contracts to not save into the database." is not grammatical in English. The database saves or does not save contracts.

Comment: I'm really not even sure what you are saying... "The database saves or does not save contracts." is neither grammatical or meaningful in English.

Hello though!

Comment: @H.R.Rambler I think the word order is incorrect. => "I have fixed an issue that caused contracts not to save into the database." should be the correct order.

Comment: I think you mean: "To Saveth Not"?
This is only a problem for puritanical "prescriptivists". An infinitive, boldly split, defies not grammar.  :-)

Humor and prodding aside. You're probably right about what Lambie is saying. However crying over split infinitive and suchlike minutia falls into a category of grammar whose archaic rules are only called upon when they match an individual's personal preferences, and there are plenty of places to engage in that unresolved debate elsewhere.
This question not does place them on trial.

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed the issue of contracts being saved or not being saved in the database.
The issue of....

Comment: To fix the issue where is not standard English even though it could be used in some circumstances.